# GCC giving an error for a file that has no errors and saying it's the wrong file format/extension

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I am compiling an app for 32bit machines since the creator of the app made it 64 bit. I made sure all the libraries and DLLs are 32bit, which they are. I have an issue when I compile, however. When I compile using sh make.sh, I get an error when it gets to the GCC building part. make.sh just makes sure that all the needed libraries are there for this project. There's no errors in the Makefile, make.sh, or any of the C++ files. I've been wasting hours trying to figure this out.

Here's a screenshot if it helps:

[image]

Comment: Did you [uncomment line 22](https://github.com/MGRich/ptr2helper/blob/master/ptr2tools-master/make.sh) for windows builds?

Comment: just remove it?

Comment: no remove the # only

Comment: wonderful!  I posted that as an answer.  If you'd care to accept it :)  Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to enable [-D_WIN32 os flag in make.sh](https://github.com/MGRich/ptr2helper/blob/master/ptr2tools-master/make.sh).